# Can I plot a bigger Bloch sphere using kaleidoscope?

Tags: programming, bloch-sphere

I'm plotting a vector on the Bloch sphere using kaleidoscope:
`from kaleidoscope import bloch_sphere`
[image]
Is there a way I can make the plot bigger? (Instead of zooming in) I tried `bloch_sphere([0,0,1],figsize=(10, 10))` but that doesn't work.

Thanks!!

Comment: That should work. I think the default is `,figsize=(350, 350) `,  so when I plot `bloch_sphere([0,0,1],figsize=(700, 700))` i do get a larger figure.

Comment: That works great!! Thanks so much:)

Comment: Glad it worked for you! No problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this [documentation shown](https://github.com/JanLahmann/kaleidoscope/blob/master/kaleidoscope/interactive/bloch/bloch3d.py)

[image]

by specifying something like `bloch_sphere([0,0,1],figsize=(700, 700))` will do it for you.